# PHP - Is there a way of looping through all elements in a JSON file if I could only fetch 100 items at one call?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I need to display all the elements/objects of a JSON file. I can currently only call an endpoint that takes an offset (starting index) and limit. The maximum number of elements you could get is 100 (the limit) at one call. I was wondering how could I get all of the elements of a JSON file and store them in an array without knowing how many elements there are in the JSON file.

Initially I tried to save the first 500 elements in an array. The problem with that was that the output size of that array was 5 and not 500 because the getElements endpoint returns a list of 100 elements, so what the array actually stored was 100 elements at each index. So for example json_array[0] contains the first 100 elements, json_array[2] contains the next 100 elements etc.

```php
$offset = 0;
$limit = 100;
$json_array = array();

while($offset < 500)
{
array_push($json_array,getElements($token,"api/Elements?offset=".$offset."&limit=".$limit));
$offset+=100;
}

echo count($json_array)
```

I am expecting to find a way to loop through the entire json file without knowing the number of elements that the file has. My final expectation is to find a way to display the number of all of these elements. Thank you!

Comment: where is `getElements` from (any framework?)? What script is running at the api-endpoint `api/Elements`?

Comment: Usually an endpoint will include some sort of meta information with the response which tells you about (for example) the total rows.  So an example of the JSON returned may help.

Comment: I don't know the implementation of the endpoint method, I just have the swagger documentation which says that the limit of returned items is 100. And we can specify a starting index which is the offset.

Comment: I am not able to provide the file now because I am on the go but the json file contains a list of products (for clothes) and the method returns a list of them.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a similar API - there is a `per_page` option and a `page` option.

Fortunately, the API I'm hitting is set up to return everything with no error if there are less results than the `per_page` value, so what I do is simply loop while I fetched 100 records.

Something like:

```
$fetched=100;
$page=0;
$per_page=100;
$total_result=array();
while($fetched==100){

  $res=json_decode(file_get_contents($API_URL."?offset=".($page*$per_page));

  $fetched=count($res);

  // add res to big result set
  for($i=0;$i<$fetched;$i++){
     $total_result[]=$res[$i];
  }

  $page++;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I actually don't think I have any pages, the products list is in one page

Comment: @pupesko sure you do.  at 100 per request, offset of 100= page 2 .  Little more of an edit coming.